# What is the traditional method of implementing TCP, Named Pipes and MSMQ?

Tags: wcf, iis-7, tcp, named-pipes

I recently learned the implementation of TCP and Named Pipes using the Windows Activation Services in IIS 7, and implementing WCF services that offer these protocols.

I understand that IIS 7 is new but not the protocols. So,

1. Before IIS 7, what's the traditional way of implementing TCP, Named Pipes and MSMQ without IIS 7?
2. What's the advantage that IIS 7 provides over the traditional methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCP and named pipes have been implemented by the Windows O/S since the early versions of Windows NT in the early 90s, and MSMQ since the later 90s. They have O/S-level ('Win32') APIs, which predate IIS 7.